# Require username/password to execute PHP script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, authentication

I'm working on a website in which I -as an admin- need to be able to access a [PHP](http://php.net/) script that no one else can. Building a whole login system with accounts would be overkill in this case, as I would be the only one using it.

So my question is, how can I create a very basic yet secure authentication system?

Given that I have an [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/), can I use the [`.htaccess`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file to forbid access to certain PHP files and ask for a certain combination of username/password?

Comment: RTFM: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Basic Auth with .htaccess see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html

And yes, you can define that only 1 file is asking for Username/Password.

Little example e.g. for file "secure.php"

```
<Files secure.php>
  AuthType basic
  AuthName "Need Login"
  AuthUserFile /path/to/.htusers
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using `.htaccess` files and `htpasswd` command.

Try to search with ".htaccess authorization" in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an .htaccess Protected Directory or file.

http://www.bignosebird.com/apache/a10.shtml